# sql syntax error while creating a demo for sql injection

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-injection

I am trying to create a login page to demonstrate a smple sql injection attack.
Below is the php code that receives input from the login.html:

```
<?php 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'sql-injection'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 
$con=@mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
/* $ID = $_POST['user']; $Password = $_POST['pass']; */ 

function SignIn() 
{ 
session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page 

if(!empty($_POST['user']) and !empty($_POST['pass'])) //checking the username and password which is coming from Sign-In.html, are they empty or have some text
 {      

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) 
        { 
                if ($_POST['pass'] == $row['pass'])
                {
                    echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; 
                }

        } 
        else 
        {   
                    echo "The db is corrupt";
        } 
} 
else{
    echo "The username and password fields cant be empty";
}
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 

SignIn(); 

} 

?>
```

The db has one table username with columns

```
UsernameID userName   pass
1          mrboolnew  mrbool123
```

I am trying to enter this in the username column:

> Y';UPDATE username SET userName='mrboolnew1' WHERE userName = 'mrboolnew';

but I get the below error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE username SET userName='mrboolnew1' WHERE userName = 'mrboolnew';'' at line 1

Can someone help me out with the injection query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`mysql_query() sends **a** unique query (multiple queries are not supported)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) That exact sql injection will not work with [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as that only allows **1** query, not multiple queries. Once it encounters the semi-colon - `;` - it will error out. [`The query string should not end with a semicolon...`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have added protection for protecting against injection attacks, perhaps without even knowing in.  `mysql_query()` sends only a single query to the database (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)).  Semicolons are not allowed; nor are multiple queries.

You'll have to try harder to inject your own code.

Comment: are they trying to deliberately inject? It seems I may not have grasped the question

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . The title is "creating a demo for SQL injection", so the injection seems intentional.   I'm not going to give advice on how to make *that* work, but there is an obvious flaw in the approach the OP is taking.

Comment: Gotcha; Ok Gordon, I didn't grasp the question then. The title is clearer than the question itself, *or it's just me* haha

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I had to re-implement the php script and was successful in doing a sql-injection.